# CSS/Flexbox: Scroll Bars on a Flex Item?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

How do you get scrollbars on a div that is a flex item? I have the following setup:

```
    <div class="main">
        <div class="search-bar">
            <input type="text"></input>
        </div>

        <div class="search-results">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="main-info">
                            Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="main-info">
                            Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="main-info">
                            Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

With the CSS:

```
    .main-info {
        width: 650px;
        height: 350px;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    }
    .main {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .search-bar {
        flex : 1;
    }
    .search-results {
        flex: 1;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
```

The entire page gets a scroll bar when the table items don't fit into the page. But what I want is for the `search-results` div to be vertically scrollable while the `search-bar` remains fixed at the top of the page. I noticed that if I specify a `max-height` for the `search-results` and give it a small value like 100px, then the div will get the scrollbar but how do I get it without specifying this min height ?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gw7f8shy/

Comment: consider adding a fiddle, it will really help.

Comment: @PouyaAtaei added

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what u r expecting.

change these CSS properties.

```
.search-bar {
    flex: 1;
    position: sticky; /* or u can use position:fixed */
    top: 0;
    z-index: 9;
}
```

```css
.main-info {
  width: 650px;
  height: inherit;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.main-info {
  height: calc(100vh - 38px);
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.search-bar {
  flex: 1;
  position: sticky;
  /* or u can use position:fixed */
  top: 0;
  z-index: 9;
}

.search-results {
  flex: 1;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 38px);
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Subway-Mobile</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="main">
    <div class="search-bar">
      <input type="text" />
    </div>

    <div class="search-results">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="main-info">
              Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="main-info">
              Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="main-info">
              Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="main-info">
              Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="main-info">
              Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="main-info">
              Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but not quite what I want...I just want the search-results div to get a scroll bar

Comment: check out my answer now @oneCoderToRuleThemAll tell me whether u got the expected op or not ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use max-height properties in css

```
<div class="main">
        <div class="search-bar">
            <input type="text"></input>
        </div>

        <div class="search-results">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="main-info">
                            Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="main-info">
                            Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="main-info">
                            Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS code here :

```
.main-info {
        width: 650px;
        height: 350px;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    }
    .main {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .search-bar {
        flex : 1;
    }
    .search-results {
        flex: 1;
        overflow-y: auto;
        max-height: 400px;
    }
```